# For in loop in swift with dynamic range

Tags: loops, for-loop, swift3

In swift, I always used the C notation like:

```
for (var i=0;i<mybuffer.count;i++) {}
```

Now in 3.0 this can not be used. 
The problem is that using

```
for i in..<mybuffer.count {}
```

will not check the value of mybuffer.count for each iteration, which leads to index out of range, in case the mybuffer.count changes.
Is there a way to overcome this?
 I could use a while statement, but I guess that there must be a way to have a for in loop with a dynamic range, right?

Comment: There doesn't have to be such a thing. In general, modifying the size of the array in a loop is discouraged. It's a common source of bugs in C because it creates tricky corner cases (it's an error to do this in ObjC with NSMutableArray). In most cases, Swift pushes you towards treating `mybuffer` as immutable, and creating a new array (using tools like `map`). It is still possible to go the other way (and there are good reasons in some cases), but it stands out by requiring `while` syntax.

Comment: @RobNapier This would not be an error in Objective-C with `NSMutableArray`. That would only be an issue with fast enumeration, not with a "normal" `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be to use a `while` loop:

```
var i = 0
while i < mybuffer.count {
    // do stuff
    i += 1
}
```